# Visualization: elliptical insights into data sets…

Tags: probability-or-statistics, visualization

I was recently reading the following paper on visualization techniques using ellipses to gain statistical insights. Elliptical visualization for looking at correlations has briefly been touched on this board as well.

[Elliptical Insights: Understanding Statistical Methods through Elliptical Geometry](http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.4881).

There are a couple of plots in the paper on quickly plotting correlations between complex data that I found quite useful and would like to replicate them. Having a function to visualize complex correlations would be useful to a lot of folks… However, my skills in MMA are lacking a bit...

[image: Scatterplot Matrices showing data, 68% data ellipses and regression lines]
[image]

Comment: I believe you'll have to construct these manually using overlays. `ListPlot` will create the scatters, and `LinearModelFit` will regress the data and give you the error information you need to calculate the ellipses. Can you take a stab at implementing the ellipse method described in the paper, or at least spell out the steps? Here's a nudge as far as splitting the data goes: `groups = Map[Tuples[Most@#, {2}] &, GatherBy[irisData, Last], {2}];
ListPlot[groups[[All, All, #]]] & /@ Range@16 // Partition[#, 4] & // TableForm`

Comment: Look at this [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2411/showing-the-correlation-of-two-variables-using-a-plot). You can find fantastic techniques related to Confidence ellipses.

Comment: Pam, if you've come up with some code that answers the question, please post it as an answer (it's allowed, in fact positively encouraged, to answer your own question).

Comment: tnx. just posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Updated with working code (tnx @rasher @mfvonh)**

Let’s start by importing [Fisher’s classic dataset on Iris flower measurements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set)…
Fisher’s classic paper [can be found here…](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/store/10.1111/j.1469-1809.1936.tb02137.x/asset/j.1469-1809.1936.tb02137.x.pdf?v=1&t=hwmm6zl2&s=1a301d6d898d580d39ac17adde3a8dcb14873d2d).

```
Needs["MultivariateStatistics`"]

(*Import Data*)
irisData = Import["http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/data/iris.csv", "CSV"];
plotLabels = {"Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Type"};
T= Transpose;
(*Parse Data and Regress, thanks @mfvonh *)

groups = Map[Tuples[Most@#, {2}] &, GatherBy[irisData, Last], {2}];
pairs = (Dimensions@groups)[[3]];
lm = Table[LinearModelFit[groups[[All, All, i]][[#]], {x}, x] & /@ Range[3], {i, 1, pairs}];
plotLabels =Flatten@
ConstantArray[{"Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width”},Sqrt@pairs];
```

Setting up plotting options:

```
(*Set up plot options *)

DodgerBlue = RGBColor[0.117603`, 0.564699`, 1.`]; 
CrimsonRed = RGBColor[0.889996`, 0.149998`, 0.209998`];
SeaGreen = RGBColor[0.180395`, 0.545106`, 0.341197`];

SetOptions[{ListPlot, SmoothHistogram}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 150, 
PlotStyle -> {CrimsonRed, SeaGreen, DodgerBlue}, 
FrameTicks -> {Automatic, Automatic, None, None}, 
BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Myriad Pro", FontTracking -> "SemiCondensed", 
FontWeight ->"Thin", FontSize -> 10}];
```

Let’s create some helper functions for the individual plots:

```
(*Elliptical Insights*)

Clear[regPlot, data, regressions, MinMax];

MinMax[x_] := Flatten[{Min[x], Max[x]}];

ellipseInsight[data_, regressions_, colors_: {CrimsonRed, SeaGreen, DodgerBlue}, ci_: 0.68] :=

Show[ {

  ListPlot[data[[1]], PlotStyle -> Lighter@colors[[1]]]
, ListPlot[data[[2]], PlotStyle -> Lighter@colors[[2]] ]
, ListPlot[data[[3]], PlotStyle -> Lighter@colors[[3]] ]

, Plot[regressions[[1]][x], {x, Min@(T@data[[1]])[[1]], Max@(T@data[[1]])[[1]]}, PlotStyle -> colors[[1]] ]
, Plot[regressions[[2]][x], {x, Min@(T@data[[2]])[[1]], Max@(T@data[[2]])[[1]]}, PlotStyle -> colors[[2]] ]
, Plot[regressions[[3]][x], {x, Min@(T@data[[3]])[[1]], Max@(T@data[[3]])[[1]]}, PlotStyle -> colors[[3]] ]

, Graphics[{colors[[1]] , Quiet@EllipsoidQuantile[data[[1]], ci]}]
, Graphics[{colors[[2]] , Quiet@EllipsoidQuantile[data[[2]], ci]}]
, Graphics[{colors[[3]] , Quiet@EllipsoidQuantile[data[[3]], ci]}]

}
, PlotRange -> Automatic
, FrameTicks -> {False, True, False, False}
, FrameStyle -> Directive[Thin, Gray]
, Axes -> False
, ImagePadding -> {{pad, pad/4}, {pad, pad/4}}
, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

Let’s generate the plots:

```
(* Generate Regression Plots *)

plots = Table[ellipseInsight[groups[[All, All, i]], lm[[i]]], {i, 1, pairs}];

(* Generate Histogram Plots For the Diagonal *)

diags = Table[i (1 + Sqrt@pairs) + 1, {i, 0, Sqrt@pairs - 1} ];

histogramsPlots =Table[
Show[MapThread[
 SmoothHistogram[(T@groups[[All, All, i]][[#1]]), 
   AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> #2] & 
 , {Range[3], {CrimsonRed, SeaGreen, DodgerBlue}}]
 , PlotRange -> {MinMax @ groups[[All, All, i, 1]], All}
 , ImagePadding -> {{pad, pad/4}, {pad, pad/4}}
 , Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[Thin, Gray]
 , FrameTicks -> {True, False, False, False}, ImageSize -> 150 
 , FrameLabel -> {"", plotLabels[[i]]}, Axes -> False], {i, diags}];


(*Merge Plots*)

Do[plots[[i (1 + Sqrt@pairs) + 1]] = histogramsPlots[[i + 1]], {i, 0, Sqrt@pairs - 1}];


(*Draw the plots*)
plots // Partition[#, 4] & // Grid
```

And here’s the sample output:
[image]

Comment: +1 - very cool you took the time to flesh this out!

Comment: tnx, was a way of learning to plot on MMA, something I wanted to do for a while…

Answer (score 20):

I don't have time to do the full-monty on the question, but perhaps this little-known functionality might be of use:

```
Needs["MultivariateStatistics`"]

(* fake some data *)
data = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[{20, 20}, {5, 5}, .75], 500];

Show[{ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> 1], 
       Graphics[{Red, EllipsoidQuantile[data, .95], 
                 Green, EllipsoidQuantile[data, .99]}]}, 
       PlotRange -> {{0, 40}, {0, 40}}]
```

[image]

Comment: this is great… simplifies stuff…