# How to Plot big data without wrong values?

Tags: plotting, data, error-propagation

I have to plot a big file with 10 data (data01{x1,y1}, data02{x2,y2}, ...., data10{x10,y10}), for example for data01 ([here is the link of data01](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtueU5Kt9JwUqUK1FBS5Vl_kSHsm?e=GXLj0G)) I get this plot with some wrong values

[image]

```
ListLogLogPlot[{data01, Table[{t, t}, {t, 0.01, 10, 0.05}]},Joined ->True,Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0.01, 10}, {0.01, 10}},PlotRangePadding -> 0,LabelStyle -> Directive[Black],GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.85]],ImageSize -> 450]
```

Since I can't detect all these wrong values, how to manipulate these in order to ignore the plot instabilities?

Thank you!

Comment: [Exclude data from a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65246/106) might be of interest

Comment: @user1066 Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Discarding points that lie outside the [95% interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule).

```
Clear[x]
lm = LinearModelFit[data01, x, x];
{lower, upper} = lm["SinglePredictionBands", ConfidenceLevel -> 0.95];

Show[ListPlot[data01], Plot[{None, lower, upper},
  {x, data01[[1, 1]], data01[[-1, 1]]}]]
```

[image]

```
{lowervals, uppervals} = Transpose[
   lm["SinglePredictionConfidenceIntervals", ConfidenceLevel -> 0.95]];

data02 = MapThread[If[And[Last[#1] > #2, Last[#1] < #3], #, Nothing] &,
   {data01, lowervals, uppervals}];

ListLogLogPlot[{data02, Table[{t, t}, {t, 0.01, 10, 0.05}]},
 Joined -> True, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{0.01, 10}, {0.01, 10}},
 PlotRangePadding -> 0, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black], GridLines -> Automatic,
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.85]], ImageSize -> 450]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much @Chris Degnen, I applied this for another data, but it also gives instabilities, in this case we adjust which parameter, ConfidenceLevel -> 0.95??

Comment: Yes, you can vary the confidence level, or use a higher order linear model e.g. `LinearModelFit[data, {x, x^2}, x]`, or use a non-linear model, and/or mean prediction intervals instead of single prediction intervals, e.g. https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/MeanAndSinglePredictionBandsForANonlinearModel/

Comment: This is impressive @Chris, I applied `ConfidenceLevel -> 1` for all data and it works perfectly, everything is fixed, I am very grateful to you, thank you so much, I hope this post will help other data manipulators.

Comment: Can you explain me @Chris the method that you have used here?

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prediction_interval): "*a prediction interval is an estimate of an interval in which a future observation will fall, with a certain probability, given what has already been observed. Prediction intervals are often used in regression analysis.*" Another example [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2420/363).

Comment: @ChrisDegnenThank you so much. I want youe email please!

Comment: I tried your method @Chris Degnen for this data [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtueU5Kt9JwUqUOM82e3-BZnJqHp?e=XpCxv5) but it doesn't work, any idea ?

Comment: Rather extreme case.  I obtained a 4PL fit and estimates for a, b, c & d with a 20 point sample from [MyCurveFit](https://mycurvefit.com). The lower bound cuts off irregular data with `nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data100, d + (a - d)/(1 + (x/c)^b), {{a, 101.6124}, {b, 2.592171}, {c, 0.03204032}, {d, 2.032935}}, x]; {lower, upper} = nlm["SinglePredictionBands", ConfidenceLevel -> 0.68]; Show[Plot[{nlm[x], lower, upper}, {x, data100[[1, 1]], data100[[-1, 1]]}], ListPlot[data100], AxesOrigin -> 0, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-0.2, Automatic}}]`

Comment: Without guesses Mathematica does the job, but with some complaints, i.e. `nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data100, d + (a - d)/(1 + (x/c)^b), {a, b, c, d}, x]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137221/discussion-between-gallagher-and-chris-degnen).

Comment: The plot is false for data between 0.01 and 0.05.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps `DeleteAnomalies` is what you are looking for:

```
dataO = DeleteAnomalies[LearnDistribution[MovingMedian[data01 , 150],Method -> "Multinormal"], data01 ];
Show[ListLinePlot[data01],ListPlot[dataO, PlotRange -> Full, PlotStyle -> Green]]
```

[image]

Comment: good method, thank you so much

Answer (score 5):

Other than using functions like `FindPeak` or `DeleteAnomalies` based on your data we can just fit a line and use it as a clipper to smoothen your data.

```
fit = FindFit[data01, a x + b, {a, b}, x];
clipper = Function[{x}, Evaluate[a x + b /. fit]]
```

> `Function[{x}, -0.0315537 + 0.993757 x]`

Now the smoothed data will be like this.

```
smoothed = If[Abs@(#[[2]] - clipper[#[[1]]]) > 0.5, {#[[1]], line[#[[1]]]}, #] & /@ data01
```

Now plotting

```
ListLogLogPlot[{smoothed, Table[{t, t}, {t, 0.01, 10, 0.05}]}, Joined -> True, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0.01, 10}, {0.01, 10}},PlotRangePadding -> 0, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black], GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.85]],
```

ImageSize -> 450]

[image]

Comment: good method, many thanks